# Slicing by Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I have an array as follows:

```
 A =
 [[  1.   2.   3.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  4.   5.   6.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  7.   8.   9.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [ 10.  11.  12.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [ 13.  14.  15.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [ 16.  17.  18.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [ 19.  20.  21.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [ 22.  23.  24.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [ 25.  26.  27.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [ 28.  29.  30.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]]
```

I also have a vector, `v=[10, 3]`, that tells me where I need to slice to obtain the submatrix at the top left-hand corner:

```
 A[0:v[0], 0:v[1]] = 
[[  1.   2.   3.]
 [  4.   5.   6.]
 [  7.   8.   9.]
 [ 10.  11.  12.]
 [ 13.  14.  15.]
 [ 16.  17.  18.]
 [ 19.  20.  21.]
 [ 22.  23.  24.]
 [ 25.  26.  27.]
 [ 28.  29.  30.]]
```

Suppose I now have an n-dimensional array, `A_n`, with a submatrix at the top left-hand corner of it, as is the case above. Again, there is a vector `v_n` that tells me the range of my submatrix.

How do I slice the n-dimensional array with the vector without writing each index range by hand i.e. `A_n[0:v_n[0], 0:v_n[1], 0:v_n[2] ...]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct a tuple of `slice` objects (which the colon representation basically represent) through a mappinng:

```
A_n[tuple(map(slice, V_n))]
```

So if `V_n = [10, 3]`, we will pass it:

```
>>> tuple(map(slice, [10, 3]))
(slice(None, 10, None), slice(None, 3, None))
```

This is basically a desugared version of what `[:10, :3]` means.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is enough to convert `A_n` into a numpy array, and then slice it using a list comprehension:

```
A_n = np.array(A_n)

A_sliced = A_n[[slice(i) for i in v_n]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code:

```
A = [[1., 2., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [4., 5., 6., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [7., 8., 9., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
     [10., 11., 12., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [13., 14., 15., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [16., 17., 18., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
     [19., 20., 21., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [22., 23., 24., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [25., 26., 27., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
     [28., 29., 30., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]
n = [10,3]
arrayA = []
for i in range(0,n[0]):
    tempArray = []
    for j in range(0,n[1]):
        tempArray.append(j)
    arrayA.append(tempArray)
print(arrayA)
```